# JavaScript - Inserting into Content section of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want my program to work like this: When i press a hyperlink in html, i want it to load new content into the "content" section. I have an example code that does this. But I am trying to insert a dygraph inside and I find that the example only passes string. The graph that i was trying to insert did not appear in the content, only basic html appeared (button, background color, etc)

```
 function loadPage(page)
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", page, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                             "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

If i'm not wrong, the loadPage function needs to be edited. But i'm not sure how. Hope you guys can answer me in a layman's term.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, even thought I might want to experiment between `xmlhttp.responseText` and `xmlhttp.response`. If you can see some HTML elements being parsed correctly, it means that you have mistakenly thought that your `dygraph` should appear like you imagine. Maybe you need to initialize your DOM with the `dygraph` API. You need to provide more information about this `dygraph` thing.

Comment: i am trying to display just any simple dygraph in the content section. something like this http://dygraphs.com/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your newly retrieved content to `dygraph` after you fetch.

```
function loadPage(page) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlhttp.open("GET", page, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                             "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
                var g = new Dygraph('content', xmlhttp.responseText, [rest of your parameters]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.. i will try and work on it.. many thanks

Comment: Hi calvin, i am sorry, but what do you mean //INITIALIZE YOUR NEW HTML ? do i insert the whole html code there?

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you see if you understand? If not please provide a working example on JSFiddle and I will fix it for you.

Comment: i think i worked it out based on your suggestions. sorry for replying so late.. i would verify your answer if i could :)